# Add view to scrollview

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, scrollview, xcode6.4

How I can add different view  which situated in storyboard to scrollview??Is it possible?If yes,please write code in swift.

Comment: you can add only view of viewcontroller not Viewcontroller directly .

Comment: @iThink Yes,how I can do it? I find example only with colors or images

Comment: Just find your viewcontroller.view (base view ) and add it to scrollView . Otherwise please elaborate more (actually i am not getting your whole requirement )